# Recursion not occurring in toString()-method

Tags: java, tostring, composite

I'm creating a composite pattern with `Bag`s and `Item`s, where the `Bag`s can contain `Item`s but the `Item`s cant contain anything.

When I use the `toString()`-method on the root, I would like every single `Entity` in that `Bag` to be printed in "natural language". At the moment it looks like the recursion is broken in the `toString()`-method, and I'm not sure why. I tried using `System.out.println(1);` before the `while`-loop, and it only printed once which is why I believe the recursion is broken.

`Item`-class;

```
public class Item extends Entity {

public Item(String theName) {
    this.name = theName;
}

public String toString() {
    String output = String.format("a %s", name);
    return output;
}
}
```

`Bag`-class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Bag extends Entity {
private List<Entity> children = new ArrayList<Entity>();

public Bag(String theName) {
    this.name = theName;
}

public void add(Entity entity) {
    children.add(entity);
}

public String toString() {
    String output = String.format("a %s", name);
    Iterator<Entity> itemIterator = children.iterator();
    output += " containing ";

    Entity current = itemIterator.next();
    while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
        output += current.toString();

        Entity next = itemIterator.next();
        if (next instanceof Item) {
            output += ", ";
        } else if (next instanceof Bag) {
            output += " and ";
        }
        current = next;
    }
    return output;
}
}
```

`Entity`-class;

```
public abstract class Entity {

protected String name;
protected int weight;

public abstract String toString();
public abstract int getWeight();

}
```

`MyFrame` containing the `main`-method;

public class MyFrame {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bag sack = new Bag("sack");
    Bag pouch = new Bag("pouch");
    Bag suitcase = new Bag("suitcase");

    Item perfume = new Item("perfume");
    Item deodorant = new Item("deodorant");
    Item toothbrush = new Item("toothbrush");

    Item hairtie = new Item("hairtie");
    Item pen = new Item("pen");
    Item sock = new Item("sock");

    Item shirt = new Item("white shirt");
    Item shirt2 = new Item("black shirt");

    pouch.add(toothbrush);
    pouch.add(perfume);
    pouch.add(deodorant);

    sack.add(pen);
    sack.add(hairtie);
    sack.add(sock);
    sack.add(pouch);

    suitcase.add(shirt);
    suitcase.add(shirt2);
    suitcase.add(sack);

    System.out.println(suitcase.toString());

}
}
```

The text I want is;
"a suitcase containing a white shirt, a black shirt and a sack containing a pen, a hairtie, a sock and a pouch containing a toothbrush, a perfume, a deodorant"

The text I get is;
"a suitcase containing a white shirt, a black shirt and"

Comment: Are you two serious? What about `output += current.toString();`?

Comment: @MaanooAk Thanks, I was so confused... :D

Comment: Once you have called next() to know what separator to output after the last item, hasNext() returns false, and thus you never write the last bag element. Use your debugger. Invert your logic: **always** call hasNext() before calling next(), and add a separator if there was a previous element. Your method would throw for an empty bag.

Comment: Also note that your chosen format is ambiguous. the default toString() generated by your IDE would be clearer, and not ambiguous.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException oops, you're right actually. I think I missed the part where `Bag`s are also `Entity`s. Erasing comments in shame...

Comment: @Mena no worries. I've erased my comments too, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException thanks for covering up my mess :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
return output;
```

to

```
return output + current;
```

You are not appending the last element to your output.

Additionally, you are calling `Iterator::next` before checking `Iterator::hasNext`, if you have an empty `Bag`, there will be a `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 1):

The iterator usage is alread criticized in the other answers; also border conditions should be taken care of: 0 or 1 children.

```
public String toString() {
    String output = String.format("a %s", name);
    if (!children.isEmpty()) {
        // Unfortunately because of the recursion the following
        // cannot be done.
        //String list = children.stream()
        //    .map(Entity::toString).collect(Collectors.join(", "));
        //output += list.replaceFirst(", ([^,]*)$", " and $1");

        // Iterating from the back reversed, allows an easy
        // discrimination of comma and "and."
        StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder();
        String separator = " and ";
        ListIterator<Entity> itemIterator = children.listIterator(children.size());
        while (itemIterator.hasPrevious()) {
            Entity entity = itemIterator.previous();
            list.insert(0, entity.toString());
            if (itemIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                list.insert(0, separator);
                separator = ", ";
            }
        }
        output += list.toString();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `stream().map(Entity::toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException indeed and I'll take the liberty to steel that snippet. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a problem with replacing the last comma with replaceFirst: say you have "a suitcase containing a shirt, a hat, a bag containing a comb, a toothbrush, a toothpaste." You don't just want to replace the *textually last* comma; instead, you need to turn that sentence into "a suitcase containing a shirt, a hat **and** a bag containing a comb, a toothbrush and a toothpaste." Here, the required sentence contains an 'and' *before* the last comma.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException and recursion was already mentioned. A pitty but the Stream solution would become too ugly.

Comment: That is indeed a pity, as the Stream solution initially looked very neat, but became very complicated due to a very minor detail.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error at the while condition

```
if (!itemIterator.hasNext()) return output;
Entity current = itemIterator.next();

while (true) {
    output += current.toString();

    if (!itemIterator.hasNext()) break;

    Entity next = itemIterator.next();
    // ......
    current = next;
}
return output;
```

You basically skip the last entity